# How to fix rotating image overlap with html and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load and rotate an image inside of a div, so far so good (https://jsfiddle.net/ab5jkybL/) except that the pic overlaps the surrounding area when it rotates. To be more specific, it does this when I use the Google logo image. It seems to act differently depending on the image type and size. In either case it either gets cut off the side of the screen or overlaps the surrounding page area unless the image is small.

I have found a few ideas to fix this (I'm currently trying to restrict the size of the div and img limits but I can't seem to get it to work correctly), but I need something that will work on all browsers, preferably back to IE6 because I'm following the rules of progressive enhancement. However, more modern ideas are also welcome (such as anything that will work for IE8 and up). I need to limit the picture size inside of the div so that it can rotate without going outside of the restricted area. Any ideas?

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
            <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1" />
        </form>
    <div id="photo"></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';
        });
    </script>
    <button id="button">rotate</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
        var curr_value = document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform;
        var new_value = "rotate(90deg)";
        if(curr_value !== ""){
        var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 90;
        new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
        }
        document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Forget IE6 and 7... Supporting those browsers is very bad practise imho. People should be actively discouraged from using those.

Comment: I agree, but none the less I would like to at least try to make it so my code can support it. If not then I will be happy with answers for IE8 and up.

Comment: can you make it into a working example in a snippet what you have so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ab5jkybL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set the div dimensions based on the image you're loading? This when you rotate, there won't be any overlap.

https://jsfiddle.net/chillichief/ab5jkybL/2/

```
<script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';

            //Get larger edge
    var largerPhotoDimension = Math.sqrt(Math.pow($("#photoimg").width() , 2) + Math.pow($("#photoimg").height() ,2) );

    //Adjust container to fit rotated image
    $("#photo").width(largerPhotoDimension);
    $("#photo").height(largerPhotoDimension);    

            });
        </script>
```

Thanks chillichief for pointing out my bad initial math :-)

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to work, not even in your jsfiddle link.

Comment: that wouldnt fix it.
the width and height must be equal to the diagonal length of the photo

`lagerPhotoDimention = sqrt($("#photoimg").width() ^ 2 + $("#photoimg").height() ^2 );`

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood what you're needing to do. I attached an image of what the result of the fiddle would be using google's logo

Comment: @chillichief You're right, it's not quite accurate. You want me to edit in your changes?

Comment: sure. remember its Math.sqrt and Math.pow to calculate the distance.

https://jsfiddle.net/chillichief/ab5jkybL/2/

i also added colors to show better that it works

Comment: anyway to do this without jquery?

Comment: @Stevo Ya, you'd replace the $ selectors with document.getelementbyId. and use offsetWidth/height vs. jquery's width()/height()

Comment: @chillichief using your fiddle link the first time i ran it it did not work, but the second time i ran it it did. any idea why that might be? I should also point out that instead of copying a fresh url into the text box i simply clicked on the box and used a previously used url from the dropdown history in the box. This might have something to do with it.